# How to check the NSString contains URL or string data?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am fresher to iOS, i am getting problem at checking string object contains URL or string?

```
NSMutableArray *Arr=[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObject:@"Welcome", @"http://abcd.com/Images/bus.png", nil];

int i;

i++;

NSString *str=[Arr objectAtIndex:i];
```

Now, i want to check condition, if string contains "Welcome", have to display on label or if it is URL , i need to display that URL image in ImageView. So how can i check it? Please help me in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of initiating both as NSStrings, try differentiating between them by making urls a NSURL (special container specifically for urls):

```
NSMutableArray* Arr = [NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObject:@"Welcome", [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abcd.com/Images/bus.png"], nil];

for(id object in Arr)
{
    if([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        NSString* string = object;
        NSLog(@"String: %@", string);
    }
    else if([object isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]])
    {
        NSURL* url = object;
        NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
NSMutableArray *Arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Welcome", @"http://abcd.com/Images/bus.png",nil];

    NSString *st=nil;
    for(NSString *string in Arr)
    {
     NSArray *matches = [detector 
                 matchesInString:string
                                    options:0
                                      range:NSMakeRange(0,     
                                     [string length])];
   for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in 
          matches) {
          if ([match resultType] ==    
         NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
        NSURL *url = [match URL];
         } else 
       {
        NSlog(@"it is a string");
       }
    }
```

}

Comment: What is the issue on this? Can anyone please explain??Because it is working fine for me

Comment: It only works on http URLs, and fails on non-url strings that start with http. Some inputs it will fail on: "ftp://google.com", "http is a protocol"

Comment: Ok but the requirement was the op wants if string contains http then it should print url. But if not then should print string.

Comment: No, the requirement was that if it was a URL it should print URL. http urls were just an example. Also, I see stack overflow messed up my comment. That was supposed to be ftp : / / google . com

Comment: Thanks catfish you are rt also i have updated my code accordingly. Please look on it and let me know if something wrong on this:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39589/discussion-between-hussain-shabbir-and-catfish-man)

Comment: what is detector here?

Comment: detector is :-   NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeTransitInformation error:&error];

Answer (score 0):

To check `NSString` is containing a URL You can Try This code

```
if ([stringName hasPrefix:@"http://"] || [stringName hasPrefix:@"https://"]) {
    //show imageVivew
}
```

Comment: Don't check the prefix, it will require changes if you ever decide to support ftp://, or another protocol. Instead use the NSURL class type, which is also a lot faster, see my post.

Comment: I agreed this solution require minor change. What only you do is to add [stringName hasPrefix:@"ftp://"] and this is not a big deal.

Comment: @SomeGuy In the question Ramesh was asking about how to check that a string contains url or not?

Comment: Although the initial question may have implied plain NSStrings, if you can think of a more robust and reliable alternative then that's probably a better answer to just answering the question as it was given. Even if all you needed to do was add an extra protocol to your if statement, it still requires code change, and in terms of maintainability, the best solution is always one that is going to be less code in the long run (and perform faster than a string check).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will help you:

```
NSMutableArray *Arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Welcome", @"http://abcd.com/Images/bus.png", nil];

if([Arr count])

{

for (NSString *str in Arr)

    {
        if([str isEqualToString:@"Welcome"])

        {
            NSLog(@"str is %@",str);

            //do whatever you want
        }

        if([str isEqualToString:@"http://abcd.com/Images/bus.png"])

        {
            NSLog(@"str is %@",str);

            //do whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```